# Is it possible in SharePoint 2013 to insert data into two list at once using REST?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have two list for example List A and List B the List A is The parent of List B
means one to many relationship

Is it possible in SharePoint 2013 to have a single form that have fields from both list

if a user submit the form it should first insert data of List A and pack the inserted id and insert data into List B based on Inserted Id of List A

to make it simple: How to create CRUD with one to many relationships using REST?

Answer (score 2):

Yep it is possible. I use this for a little Timesheet application. First, the list setup:

1. Timesheet - The parent, contains metadata
2. Timesheet Entries - The child, can be many entries per parent

   - Has a "Timesheet" lookup column back to the parent list
   - The Column shows the ID of the parent Timesheet
   - You can't delete the parent Timesheet if there are existing entries (restrict delete turned on)

Second, I created a regular HTML form with jQuery and Knockout.js. This is dependent on your requirements so you can make this however you want and then include your HTML page using a Content Editor Web Part.

Finally, to answer your question, you create your JavaScript for handling the AJAX operations. For example, creating a timesheet (the PARENT):

```
self.CreateTimesheet = function(title, weekEnding, ownerId) {
    var data = {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TimesheetListItem' },
        Title: title,
        Week_x0020_Ending: weekEnding,
        State: 'Started',
        OwnerId: ownerId
    };
    var promise = $.ajax({
        'url': self.sheetUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Then, you can create the Timesheet Entries (the CHILDREN) by populating `TimesheetId` (remember this is my lookup column back to my parent list):

```
self.CreateTimesheetEntry = function() {
    var item = {
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Timesheet_x0020_EntriesListItem' },
        'Title': self.job(),
        'Entry_x0020_UserId': self.userId,
        'Entry_x0020_Date': self.entryDate,
        'TimesheetId': self.timesheetId
        // More fields if you want.....
    };
    var promise = $.ajax({
        'url': self.entryUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
    return promise;
};
```

I recommend packaging all your AJAX functions into a shared object, that way you can define your constants at the top.

```
self.siteUrl = "/company";
self.sheetUrl = self.siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'254561B8-20E1-40FE-A710-CF9DBA07182C')/Items";
self.entryUrl = self.siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'32C561F2-EF45-402D-9EBB-BF98A831A4EB')/Items";
```